# Comparing columns values and change their places by condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are three simple tables. `Actor`, `Film`, `Film_actor`.

`Film_Actor` table:

```
 actor_id     | film_id
--------------+---------------------------
     1        |  3
     2        |  4
```

`Actor` table:

```
 actor_id   | first_name                  | last_name
------------+-----------------------------+----------
     1      | Daniel                      |  Craig
     2      | Eva                         |  Green
```

`Film` table:

```
 film_id     | title                      
-------------+---------------------------------------
    3        | Casino Royale
    4        | Colombo
```

I would like *to find two actors who cast together the most and list the titles
of those movies. Moreover, `actor_id` of the `first_actor` should be lower than `actor_id` of the second_actor*.

So the desired result should look like this:

```
first_actor     | second_actor  | title
----------------+---------------+---------------
Daniel Craig    | Eva Green     | Casino Royale
```

I've written the following code:

```
SELECT   
        ac1.actor_id first_actor_id
        , ac1.first_name + ' ' + ac1.last_name   first_actor
        , ac2.actor_id second_actor_id
        , ac2.first_name + ' ' + ac2.last_name second_actor
        ,count(*) FilmCount
    FROM
        Actor as ac1 
        INNER JOIN Film_Actor as fa1 ON fa1.actor_id = ac1.actor_id
        INNER JOIN Film_Actor as fa2 ON fa1.film_id = fa2.film_id
        INNER JOIN Actor as ac2 ON fa2.actor_id = ac2.actor_id 
            and fa1.actor_id < ac2.actor_id
        INNER JOIN Film as fi ON fa1.film_id = fi.film_id
    GROUP BY 
        ac1.actor_id
        , ac1.first_name
        , ac1.last_name   
        , ac2.actor_id
        , ac2.first_name
        , ac2.last_name
```

In my view, the above code is a little bit clumsy as the code makes checking of this condition  **`actor_id` of the `first_actor` should be lower than `actor_id` of the second_actor*`** just for second actor.

Is it possible to improve comparing `actor_id` of the `first_actor` with `actor_id` of the second_actor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `inner join`s are used, you'll only ever be returned rows where the `first_actor_id` is smaller than the `second_actor_id`, so the code works as intended.

If I understand correctly, you want the code to check that `first_actor_id` is smaller than `second_actor_id` AND `second_actor_id` is bigger than `first_actor_id`. However, those two conditions are the same so you only need one of them.

As a sidenote, your code will not work as intended for the following reasons: (1) It will bring back any actors who have starred in ONE movie together, rather than two, and (2) it does not list the movie names they have starred in.

The first problem is easy to fix; add `HAVING count(*) >= 2` to the end of the statement.

The second problem depends on the version of SQL Server you are using (use `SELECT @@VERSION` to find out):

- If you're running SQL Server 2017 or later, exchange `count(*)` in the `SELECT` for [`STRING_AGG(fi.title, ', ')`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) (documentation linked) – this will give you a comma-separated list of films.
- If not, the best way to concatenate strings from a group is the "stuff XML path" method. A quick search online should explain how this trick works.